# HAProxy - Add response header based on request host

Tags: haproxy, request, headers

I have a HAProxy set up to redirect traffic to a few internal servers.

What I'm trying to do is to set some response headers, based on the request host. Unfortunately I can't get it to work.

Current settings look like this

```
acl mywebsite req.hdr(host) -i example.com

http-response set-header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN if mywebsite
http-response set-header X-XSS-Protection 1;mode=block if mywebsite
http-response set-header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff if mywebsite
```

As I understood http-response set-header can't read the request header. Is there any way around this?

Comment: No idea, but what is "if example"? Did you mean "if mywebsite"?

Comment: jep. didn't notice that :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `set-var`

```
   http-request set-var(txn.host) hdr(Host)
   acl myhost var(txn.host) -m str example.com
   http-response set-header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN if myhost
```

Comment: can't vote you up because of low rep but thanks a lot! that solved it.